# products thumbnail images missing when share it any social networks

Tags: magento-1.9

when i share products on any social networks products thumbnail images missing all time

please help me any buddy 
i'm use magento 1.9.2.2

[image]

http://prnt.sc/cnrliu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meta is having below image url:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://itsthyme.com/skin/frontend/base/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg"/>
```

and facebook is fetching that url for sharing.

You need replace the `og:image` meta tag with your product image.

Comment: can u send me more details where i replace it og:image in metatag please help me

Comment: That depends on the theme you installed.

Comment: Great! Tick this as answer if this helper you, so that it will be helpful to other users with similar issue

Answer (score 0):

In your local.xml for the theme, between

```
   <reference name="head">

   </reference>
```

add in:

```
<block type="core/template" name="social.code" template="page/html/social-code.phtml"/>
```

Then create a new file in yourpackage/yourtheme/template/page/html and call it social-code.phtml.

Inside this file you can put meta tags for the main social media sites:

```
<?php 
if (Mage::registry('current_product')) {
        $product    = Mage::registry('current_product');
        $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
} //load product information
?>


<?php if ($product) : ?>
//echo product image URL below
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(600,315); ?>" />
<!-- Other tags can go here, e.g. title, type, url -->
<?php endif; ?>
```